# JPEG image does not end with EOI marker although it is not truncated

Tags: python-3.x, jpeg, truncated

I tried to catch truncated JPEG or PNG images by checking if the last bytes of the image has EOI marker (for JPEG is was 'ffd9' in last 2 bytes, and for PNG it was '49454e44ae426082' in last 8 bytes)

But I found that this approach cannot work all the time because of extra data in the image. Some images include extra bytes after EOI....

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ggJk.png)

Is there an offset for the EOI so I can stick with this bytes comparing solution? or do I have to find another way to check if image is truncated?

I cannot use try-except by using global variable PIL LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES because my process is based on multi-thread context.

It would be nice if I can find solution for all JPEG, PNG images.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason why normal JPEG image did not end with EOI. There are some images which have a data after its EOI. It's called [tailer](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=4374.0).

PNG also has that kind of things so if you deal with different type of images you should know about the variations of the data around EOI.